# add a RPC password to your bitcoin.conf file

Tags: settings, rpc, bitcoin, bitcoind

I'm following instructions [here](https://developer.bitcoin.org/examples/intro.html) and it says that I will find a `bitcoin.conf` file `Windows: %APPDATA%\Bitcoin\` and

> To use bitcoind and bitcoin-cli, you will need to add a RPC password to your bitcoin.conf file. Both programs will read from the same file if both run on the same system as the same user, so any long random password will work: rpcpassword=change_this_to_a_long_random_password

However When I navigate to `%APPDATA%\Bitcoin\` I don't see a `bitcoin.conf` file. [image]

So What do I do? Do I add a `bitcoin.conf` file? There is a `bitcoin-conf.md` file in doc in my bitcoin install directory so maybe somthing todo with that? I really don't know. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *create* this file and put a single line `rpcpassword=<your_password>` in it.

`bitcoin-conf.md` contains documentation for this `btcoin.conf` and particularily states:

> The configuration file is not automatically created; you can create it using your favorite text editor.

Recommended reading this doc. It may help you to facilitate running your node.

Comment: Wondering why someone is downwoting answers with no comments.

I'd really like to know what is wrong with my answer. Can this person explain? I do not think so.

Answer (score 2):

1. That guide does not take into account the fact that you *do not **have** to* add any RPC user or password to your configuration file for the past some years.
   Bitcoind will generate a cookie that allows the CLI (command line interface) to communicate with the Bitcoin daemon using RPC without the user having had to give it a single thought.
2. That is a developers' guide, so developers may have more complex requirements that are solved if they specify their own RPC authentication settings, such as running multiple wallets, or possibly exchange software that communicates with the wallet or multiple wallets.
3. bitcoin.conf being optional, it is not by default created, and is not needed for ordinary usage, only becoming necessary when the user or developer has particular, non-default settings to set.
4. The possible settings can be found by the help command `bitcoind -help` and lists a number of command line parameters (beginning with a dash or hyphen) that can be typed or pasted after `bitcoind`  on the command line, but can be put in a text file named `bitcoin.conf` without the minus sign before the command. For example:  `-connect=IPAddress` becomes simply `connect=IPAddress` in the conf file.
5. For creating suitable rpcauth (username and hashed password), and rpcuser and rpcpassword values, I've found some resources such as https://github.com/jlopp/bitcoin-core-rpc-auth-generator

Rather than serving JLopp's RPC auth generator locally you can simply copy from, or use a Python script found in the Bitcoin repository under the folder named "share", you will see a folder called `rpcauth` which contains the `rpcauth.py` script and a small explanatory file called `README.md`.